# What happened to Maven Polyglot?

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

What happened to the Maven Polyglot project that used to be at http://polyglot.sonatype.org/?

As described in [this article](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2009/10/21/writing-your-pom-files-groovy-sneek-preview-maven-3s-polyglot-feat),

> One exciting new feature in Maven 3 is it's ability to work with pom files written in non-XML notations. The Maven core now provides an underlying DSL to access the Maven internals, and write POM files in the language of your choice. This currently includes scripting languages like Groovy, Ruby, and others. In short, you will be able to write a DSL for virtually any scripting language you like that can hook into the Maven internals and pilot the Maven build process.

There are several additional articles on the web that I've found referencing the feature.

- http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/article/maven-learn-material/maven3/maven3-pom-using-groovy-ruby-scala-yaml-sonatype-polyglot
- http://mattgivney.blogspot.com/2011/05/maven-3-polyglot-support.html

But the polyglot site now redirects to sonatype.org and I can find no mention of this feature in the [Maven 3 release notes](http://maven.apache.org/release-notes-all.html).

So what happened? Was it cut or is it in there and just not documented in the release notes? If it did make the cut for Maven 3 could you point to some documentation. I am also interested in the translator tool mentioned by the first article I linked to.

Comment: I'd ask on the Maven mailing list. Last I saw was some snapshots which should still be floating around.

Comment: I've read in a blog (couldn’t find it any more, think is was in a gradle comparison interview with J. v. Zyl) that polyglot maven was stopped and will be replaced by something else. The very precise answer of the week. 
It was interesting indeed - sad it didn’t take off :/

Comment: By the looks of [this commit history](https://github.com/etesla/tesla/commits/master), that guy is definitely up to something...

Comment: For those looking for a drop in replacement for maven that can use ruby to define builds take a look at Apache Buildr, http://buildr.apache.org/.

Comment: Meanwhile, you can take a look to http://github.com/wikier/piy

Comment: Here's a fresh guide on Polyglot from 2023: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-polyglot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There has been an update on the maven users list from Jason van Zyl: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/What-happened-to-Polyglot-Maven-td5715529.html

> I'm still working on it along with a few others. Dhanji has the [Atom markup working](https://github.com/dhanji/sitebricks/blob/master/pom.atom), Kristian has implemented a [Ruby DSL](https://gist.github.com/3244352), and Jason Dillon has implemented a [Groovy DSL](https://gist.github.com/3244367) which creates synthetic plugins to bind arbitrary scripting to Maven's lifecycle. My original was to see how Maven's infrastructure could be leveraged by other markups and DSLs. These examples do render to an interoperable format insofar as consumers go. Maven itself obviously cannot run a Ruby DSL but if you like the Ruby DSL you can use it to build an not affect consumers: you can build and deploy to a Maven repository and someone else can consume the dependency with stock Maven.
>
> I have all the early adopters I can deal with one-on-one right now, because I can't deal with many really, but if you have more than a passing interest feel free to email me privately.

looks like it is still alive :-)

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 12):

This project is now named [tesla-polyglot](https://github.com/tesla/tesla-polyglot). I've just completed the Scala DSL for it, and tesla-polyglot should be released very soon now. We're just waiting on Maven 3.1.1 to roll out of the door.

Comment: It would be nice if the old project pages did not simply vanish (and point back to sonatype.org) but gave a brief explanation of what happened and a link onwards.

Comment: So with Maven 3.1.1 (indeed 3.2.1) having been released, is there any news on this, Christopher?

Answer (score 7):

You won't believe it, but [it's released](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22io.takari.polyglot%22%20AND%20a%3A%22polyglot%22) (if you can call a 0.1 version a release).

Answer (score 5):

As of April 2016,
the home page is https://github.com/takari/polyglot-maven ,
the latest release is `0.1.15`

There is [Polyglot Maven IDE Pack](http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/polyglot-maven-ide-pack/) for Eclipse, that includes some plugins.

There is also maven-tiles project https://github.com/repaint-io/maven-tiles ,
and [quick trying out](https://github.com/takari/polyglot-maven/issues/82) what Maven flavor works well shows that Groovy does better than others.

Be aware of [Babylon Tower problem](https://github.com/takari/polyglot-maven/issues/15), so it is actually better when most of developers use the same flavor.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The latest info comes from [here](http://takari.io/2014/02/03/maven-speed.html)

"Polyglot for Maven is still moving along and we've seen a lot of activity recently on the Ruby DSL by Cristian Meier from the JRuby team, and the Scala DSL by Chris Hunt from Typesafe. We hope that this initial work can serve as inspiration for helping the POM evolve. For those interested in what the XML alternatives can look like you can take a look at the existing implementations:

Ruby DSL
Groovy DSL
Scala DSL
YAML
Atom"