# Maven 3's support for Groovy poms

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am investigating the use of Maven 3's support for Groovy poms to aid the build process within my team.

From my initial readings, I can only find articles from 2 years ago mentioning it as a feature, although not part of core Maven. 
Link to Polyglot Maven seem to redirect to the Sonatype homepage.

I have read the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170057/what-happened-to-maven-polyglot) related question, I don't fully understand what it means.

Does this mean that Maven 3 supports the generation of Groovy poms or not? Would appreciate it someone could explain in simple terms as to what this means.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Jason van Zyl, who is the founder of the Maven project and the CTO of Sonatype, is working on it, in sort of a private beta. It is not a part of the released version of Maven 3.

See [this email](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg126205.html) from Jason

Answer (score -3):

What's the problem with the build process? Do you need groovy poms to get it into your team? pom.xml files will usually not written by hand. You should IDE's for that purpose. Maven 3 does not support of Groovy pom's.

Comment: If you need an IDE to configure your pom.xml, that's a sure sign that you're not paying attention to what's happening in it, nor is your architecture well-modularized.