# Is there a simple project build/dependency management tool for Java projects?

Tags: java, maven, ant, ivy, leiningen

I've been using Maven and ant+ivy so far but I think it is rather hard to maintain all the configuration for them.

What I'd really like to have is something like leiningen which does not need any xml and you can manage the dependencies in code (in clojure code in case of leiningen). It also comes with a handy cli tool.

I know that leiningen uses maven internally so it is not a problem if your suggestion uses maven **internally** as well so a good abstraction which simplifies things and **requires no interaction with maven/ant/ivy** will be equally good for me.

Comment: As you are looking for a Java solution, I did not post it as an answer: `sbt` uses Scala as DSL, and compiles mixed Scala/Java projects fine. It uses ivy internally. You can model aggregate projects and dependencies in the DSL.

Comment: Is it http://www.scala-sbt.org/ ?

Comment: Yes, it's scala-sbt.org

Comment: ANT is the king of Java build tools, solid reliable, but set in his ways. Still capable of learning new tricks (ivy) but really just keeping the kingdom ticking along. Maven is the crown prince, lots of new ideas and finally starting to persuade the populace that he'll make a good king. Gradle is the younger prince, studious, clever, learning lessons from his predecessors. Perhaps one day he'll poison his brother and persuade the king to retire :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use pure maven or gradle, as it is easier to create build scripts, but would steer away from ant.

Ivy is an underused dependency management solution, and I personally have only cursory experience (as in building artifacts but not managing them) and I have never maintained an ivy build, but seems pretty straightforward. One thing to consider is availability of plugins and readily built artifacts(which is proportional to popularity) and maven is the clear leader.

So, my recommendation would be pure maven or gradle.

Edit: In recent years it has become modern for some repo owners to maintain both an ivy and a maven build to increase their code's exposure. If you were to do that, gradle would be simpler as it provides a nice abstraction on top of the nitty gritty maven/ivy stuff, once you are to write your scripts.

Comment: I don't want to use maven as I've said in my question.

Comment: you also said it is not a problem if our suggestions include maven :)

Comment: I provided an example of leiningen which requires **no interaction** with maven. I edited my question. What is gradle good for? I've only heard of it once or twice.

Comment: gradle is fairly easy to script with, has somewhat major support, and is fairly well known/documented/has examples.

Comment: you can check astyanax, for example, which is built using gradle. https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax. Using gradle, you can also, of course, release your artifacts as maven or ivy, as you will find out if you check their gradle scripts.

Comment: Why would you use gradle+maven instead of gradle OR maven?

Comment: @JeffStorey you are right, it doesn't make sense to use both as a build tool.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest gradle. Gradle is both a dependency management and build system. You write your build scripts in groovy code, no xml. gradle can work with existing ivy or maven repos. Its configuration tends to be a lot less verbose than maven's and it's very flexible (since you can write code in your build script when needed).

There is plenty of documentation at http://www.gradle.org/documentation

Answer (score 3):

There used to be a project called Polyglot Maven which was maven configured in code not xml.  Some detail is given about its current status here: [What happened to Maven Polyglot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170057/what-happened-to-maven-polyglot)

I also found [Buildr](http://buildr.apache.org/index.html) (for building Java projects, with config written in Ruby).

I think it'd be worth clarifying why it is you find the configuration for maven difficult to maintain.  Certainly the XML can be pretty nasty but there's lots of tooling available in IDEs etc.  If its the actual project structure and or build lifecycle that's difficult (and it can be, especially with multimodule builds) then a solution that's based on maven probably won't be much better.